# iterate over Grails controller model

Tags: grails, groovy

Say I have a controller action like the following:

```
def someAction = {

    if (someCondition) {
        [foo: 1, bar: 2] 
    } else {
        [foo2: 4, bar2: 6, baz2: 6]
    }
}
```

In `someAction.gsp` I don't know what the keys of the model are. Is there some way that I can iterate over the keys and values of the model without knowing the key names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All model attributes are available in the `request` object. You can iterate this object like this:

```
    <g:each var="item" in="${request}">
      ${item.key} = ${item.value}<br/>
    </g:each>
```

Note that the `request` object will hold **all** request attributes, a lot of information that you're probably not interested in.

Another way to accomplish what you want is putting all your model attributes in one map, like this:

```
    if (someCondition) {
       [result:[foo: 1, bar: 2]] 
    } else {
       [result:[foo2: 4, bar2: 6, baz2: 6]]
    }
```

This way you can isolate your attributes from other request attributes. In this case you'll have to iterate your model keys using the `result` map:

```
    <g:each var="item" in="${result}">
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was the same as this one.

Comment: If You do it the other way ( [result:[foo 1, bar 2]] ), you can change ${request} to ${result}

Answer (score 1):

Use [pageScope](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tag%20Libraries/pageScope.html):

```
<ul>
    <g:each var="item" in="${pageScope.variables}">
        <li>${item.key} = ${item.value}</li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

But note that you won't be able to distinguish between the controller model values and those from the framework.

Comment: This is the correct solution to see all of the variables available to the render scope.